# How to prove $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\cot^2\left( \frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)=\frac{n(2n-1)}{3}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Identity involving binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37971/identity-involving-binomial-coefficients)

how to prove
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^{n}\cot^2\left( \frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)=\frac{n(2n-1)}{3}
$$
another
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n{\binom {2k} {n} \binom {2n-2k} {n-k}}=4^n
$$

Comment: Is it intentional that the second sum contains zero terms for $k < \dfrac n 2$ or do you intend $\binom {2n} k$ in place of $\binom {2k} n$?

Comment: for the first question take a look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173447/proving-sum-limits-l-1n-sum-limits-k-1n-1-tan-frac-lk-pi-2n1-t/173649#173649)

Comment: and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2343/19538)

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/72661/12042), as corrected a few months ago, gives a complete proof of the second identity. It’s a more understandable version of the proof in the Sved article in the *Math. Intelligencer* mentioned [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/37984/12042).