# Prove that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{\cos^2\frac{\pi k}{n}}=n^2$ for odd $n$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, summation

In old popular science magazine for school students I've seen problem

> Prove that $\quad $
>   $\dfrac{1}{\cos^2 20^\circ} + 
> \dfrac{1}{\cos^2 40^\circ} + 
> \dfrac{1}{\cos^2 60^\circ} + 
> \dfrac{1}{\cos^2 80^\circ} = 40. $

How to prove more general identity:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}
\hline \\
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{\cos^2\frac{\pi k}{n}}=n^2 \\
\hline
\end{array}
,  \qquad \mbox{ where } \ n \ \mbox{ is odd.}$$

Comment: 40 isn't the square of an integer, so why do you think the problems are related?

Comment: @Mercy: $\dfrac{1}{\cos 0^\circ} + \dfrac{1}{\cos 20^\circ} + \dfrac{1}{\cos 40^\circ} + \ldots+ \dfrac{1}{\cos 160^\circ} =81=9^2$.

Comment: @Mercy Actually, it is 81 that is a square. The sum abouve doesn't contain $k=0$ and is only the first half of the other terms.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: Cool question, I have a suspicion you should add the complex-analysis tag

Comment: The expression $$\frac{1}{\cos^2 x} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1-\sin x}+\frac{1}{1+\sin x}\right)$$

So this can be written as $$\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\frac{1}{1-\sin\pi k/n}$$

Comment: Oops, forgot the half-factor, but still basically true.

Comment: Does the fourth power give you something similar?

Comment: @Michael, my answer below generalizes to this case by taking instead $f(z) = (2/(z+z^{-1}))^4$. In this you'll find that the sum becomes $\tfrac{1}{3}n^2 (2 + n^2)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since $n$ is odd, the numbers $u_k=\cos k\pi/n$ are the same as the numbers $\cos 2k\pi/n$, i.e. the distinct angles $\theta$ satisfying $n\theta=0$ (mod $2\pi$).  We think of them as the roots of the equation $\cos n\theta=1$.  Writing
$$\cos n\theta = \cos^n\theta - \binom{n}{2}\cos^{n-2}\theta\sin^2\theta \cdots \pm n\cos\theta \sin^{n-1}\theta$$
and using $\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta$, we see that the $u_k$'s are the roots of the polynomial
$$p(u)=u^n - \binom{n}{2}u^{n-2}(1-u^2) \pm n u(1-u^2)^{(n-1)/2} + 1.$$
Note that all powers of $u$ which occur are odd (except for the constant term).
The reciprocals $1/u_k$ are the roots of the "reverse polynomial"
$$r(u)=u^n p(1/u) = u^n + a_{n-1} u^{n-1} + \cdots,$$
where $a_{n-1}=\pm n$ and $a_{n-2}=0$.

The sum in question is the sum of the squares of the roots of $r(u)$, i.e. $a_{n-1}^2 - 2a_{n-2} = n^2$.

Comment: Thank you. It was most elementary proof (as for me).

Answer (score 12):

Whenever I see a problem like this, I think [Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

The Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind, $T_m(x)$, are defined so that:

$$T_m(\cos \theta) = \cos m\theta$$

$T_m$ is an $m$th degree polynomial, and the roots of $T_m(x)-1$ are exactly $\cos 2\pi k/m$ for $k=0,1,\dots,m-1$.

When $m=2n$ is even, we can write $$T_{2n}(x)=1+C\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(x^2-\cos^2\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)$$ for some constant $C$. The occurrence of those $\cos^2\frac{k\pi}{n}$ suggested this might be a good approach.

Now, given a polynomial $p(x)=a_mx^m + a_{m-1}x^{m-1}\dots +a_0$, with non-zero roots $r_0,\dots, r_{m-1}$, we have formulas:
$$\sum \frac{1}{r_k} = -\frac{a_1}{a_0}$$
And:
$$\sum_{i< j} \frac{1}{r_ir_j} = \frac{a_2}{a_0}$$

So $$\sum \frac{1}{r_k^2} = \left(-\frac{a_1}{a_0}\right)^2 - 2\frac{a_2}{a_0}$$

Now let $p(x)=T_{2n}(x)-1$. The roots of $p$ are $r_k=\cos \frac{k\pi}{n}$ for $k=0,\dots,2n-1$, and the roots are non-zero since $n$ is odd. We know that $p(x)$ is even, so $a_1=0$. Finally, we know that $\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} \frac{1}{r_k}^2$ is twice the sum that you are looking for.

So your sum is now reduced to finding $-\frac{a_2}{a_0}$ where the $a_0,a_2$ are coefficients of $p(x)$. Since $p(0)=T_{2n}(\cos \pi/2)-1 = \cos n\pi - 1 = -2$, so we know that $a_0=-2$. So $\sum r_k^{-2} = a_2$. (Again, we use $n$ odd here.)

So we need to prove that $a_2=2n^2$.

Now, $a_2=\frac{1}{2}T_{2n}^{''}(0)$. Let $f(x)=\cos 2nx = T_{2n}(\cos x)$. Differentiating we get:

$$-2n\sin 2nx = -T_{2n}^{'}(\cos x)\sin x$$

Differentiating both sides again:

$$-4n^2\cos 2nx = T_{2n}^{''}(\cos x)(\sin^2 x) - T_{2n}^{'}(\cos x)\cos x$$

Putting in $x=\pi/2$, then $\cos x=0$, $\sin x=1$, and $\cos 2nx=-1$. Therefore, we get $$4n^2 = T_n^{''}(0)\\a_n=\frac{1}{2}T_{2n}^{''}(0)=2n^2$$

and therefore your sum is $n^2$.

---

Note: Any symmetric rational function with rational coefficients of $\{\cos 2\pi k/n\mid k=0,\dots,n-1\}$ will be rational by this argument.

Comment: Thank you. Nice approach with Chebyshev polynomials.

Answer (score 9):

I believe I first came across this trick in [this paper by Szenes](http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9402003), so check out section 3 in that for more details.

Consider the form
$$\mu_n(z) = n\frac{dz}{z} \frac{z^n + z^{-n}}{z^n-z^{-n}}$$
and the function
$$f(z) = \frac{4}{(z+z^{-1})^2}.$$
Your sum is the sum of the $f(z_k)$, where $z_k = \exp(\pi i k/n)$, $k = 0, \dots, n-1$. Note first of all that for these particular values of $z$, $$f(z_k) = \mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=z_k} f \mu_n.$$
Note also that the same formula holds with $z_k$ replaced by $z_k^{-1}$, and that $\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=\infty} f\mu_n = \mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=0} f\mu_n = 0.$ Moreover, $\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z= \pm i} f\mu_n = -n^2$. It follows from the residue theorem that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(z_k) = -\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=i} f\mu_n + \mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z=-i} f\mu_n\right) = n^2.$$

Comment: Ah, interesting. I was thinking all the time this should be doable with $ \frac1{\cos^2\alpha}=\frac2{1+\cos 2\alpha}=2(1-\cos2\alpha+\cos^22\alpha-\cos^32\alpha\pm\ldots)$ and character orthogonality, but ran into dead ends ...

Comment: My own first approach was to somehow relate the sum of the question to the [quadratic Gauss sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum) to which it is very similar. Indeed, many of the formulas given on that page can be proved in a fashion much like the above.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer using complex analysis.

Answer (score 6):

In equation $(7)$ of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/173858), I compute that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right)=n(2n+1)
$$
Thus, with $n=2m+1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{\cos^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2m}\sec^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m+1}\right)\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^m\tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{2m+1}\right)+2(m+1)\\[6pt]
&=2m(2m+1)+2(m+1)\\[12pt]
&=(2m+1)^2\\[12pt]
&=n^2
\end{align}
$$

---

**Residue Theory Answer**

For odd $n$, consider the function
$$
f(z)=\frac{n/z}{z^n-1}\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^2\tag{1}
$$
All the singularities are simple, except the singularity at $-1$.
$$
\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^2=1-\frac4{z+1}+\frac4{(z+1)^2}\tag{2}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\frac{n/z}{z^{\raise{2pt}n}-1}=\frac{n-n(n+1)z^n}{z^2(z^{\raise{2pt}n}-1)^2}\tag{3}
$$
Using $(2)$ and $(3)$, we get the residue of $f$ at $-1$ to be
$$
-4\cdot\frac{-n}{-1-1}+4\cdot\frac{n+n(n+1)}{(-1-1)^2}=n^2\tag{4}
$$
The residue of $f$ at $0$ is $-n$ and the residue at each $n^{\text{th}}$ root of unity is $-\tan^2(\theta/2)$.

Since the integral of $f$ over an increasing circle vanishes, the sum of the residues must be $0$. Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=n^2-n\tag{5}
$$
and therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sec^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=n^2\tag{6}
$$

Comment: Using the half-angle formula for cosine, could you instead consider $ f(z) = \displaystyle\frac{4z}{(z+1)^{2}} \frac{n/z}{z^{n}-1}$?

Comment: @RandomVariable: $\displaystyle\frac{4z}{(z+1)^2}=1-\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^2$, so I imagine so.

Answer (score 5):

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/173649/19538) we know that
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\tan^2\frac{\pi k}{2m+1}=m(2m+1)
$$
Similarly
$$
\sum\limits_{k=m+1}^{2m}\tan^2\frac{\pi k}{2m+1}=
\sum\limits_{l=1}^{m}\tan^2\frac{\pi (2m+1-l)}{2m+1}=
\sum\limits_{l=1}^{m}\tan^2\frac{\pi l}{2m+1}=m(2m+1)
$$
Since $\cos^{-2}\alpha=1+\tan^2\alpha$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2m}\frac{1}{\cos^2\frac{\pi k}{2m+1}}
&=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2m} 1 +\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2m}\tan^2\frac{\pi k}{2m+1}\\
&=2m+1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\tan^2\frac{\pi k}{2m+1}+\sum\limits_{k=m+1}^{2m}\tan^2\frac{\pi k}{2m+1}\\
&=2m+1+m(2m+1)+m(2m+1)=(2m+1)^2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: +1 This one is a classic! It even works so as to calculate $\zeta(2),\zeta(4)$ pretty nicely.