# limit question $\lim\limits_{x\to0}(100\csc^2(x)-\csc^2(\frac{x}{10}))$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How can I find this limit?
$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(100\csc^2(x)-\csc^2\left(\frac{x}{10}\right)\right)$$
Please help me to find this limit.

Comment: With these kinds of problems, the first thing I'll usually do is try breaking down CSC and any other trig functions into other trig functions that are easier to deal with. Which usually helps at leas somewhat.

Comment: Try Maclaurin series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that when $x\to0$, $\sin(x)\sim x-\frac{x^3}{6}$
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}100\csc^2(x)-\csc^2(\frac{x}{10})&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{100\sin^2(\frac{x}{10})-\sin^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)\sin^2(\frac{x}{10})}\\&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(10\sin(\frac{x}{10})-\sin(x)\right)\times\lim_{x\to0}\frac{10\sin(\frac{x}{10})+\sin(x)}{\sin^2(x)\sin^2(\frac{x}{10})}\\&\sim_0\left(10\left(\frac{x}{10}-\frac{\frac{x^3}{1000}}{6}\right)-x+\frac{x^3}{6}\right)\times\left(\frac{2x}{\frac{x^4}{100}}\right)=33\end{align}$$

Comment: I apologise for doing this again, but how did you compute the limit with the quotient to be $2x/(x^4/100)$?

Comment: @MathsMatador Note that we also have $\sin(x)\sim x$ as $x\to0$.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: write $\csc x=\frac{1}{\sin x}$, make the fractions have the same denominator, multiply and divide with $x^4$, factor the difference of squares, and use L'Hôpitals rule.