# How prove that $\frac{1}{\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2n}}+\frac{1}{\sin^2\frac{2\pi}{2n}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sin^2\frac{(n-1)\pi}{2n}} =\frac{2}{3}(n-1)(n+1)$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

How prove that sum 
$$\frac{1}{\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2n}}+\frac{1}{\sin^2\frac{2\pi}{2n}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sin^2\frac{(n-1)\pi}{2n}} =\frac{2}{3}(n-1)(n+1)$$

Comment: This will be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544228/is-sum-k-1m-1-frac1-sin2-frack-pim-fracm2-13-true-for-m?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To develop further on `Jean-Claude Arbaut`'s comment, you'll find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544228/is-sum-k-1m-1-frac1-sin2-frack-pim-fracm2-13-true-for-m?rq=1) the proof that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{\sin^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)}}=\dfrac{(n-1)(n+1)}{3}$$
All you have to do now, is show that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{\sin^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{\color{red}{2n}}\right)}}=\color{red}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{\sin^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{\color{red}{n}}\right)}}$$