# How can I prove this ? $\sum\limits_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{\sin^2(\frac{i \pi}{2 N})} = \frac{1}{3}(2N^2+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series, sums-of-squares

$$\sum_{i=1}^N   \frac{1}{\sin^2(\frac{i \pi}{2 N})} = \frac{1}{3}(2N^2+1)$$

How can I prove this ?

Thank you.

Comment: see [Is $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{\sin^2\frac{k\pi}{m}}=\frac{m^2-1}{3}$ true for $m\in\mathbb N$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544228/is-sum-k-1m-1-frac1-sin2-frack-pim-fracm2-13-true-for-m)

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251060/how-prove-that-frac1-sin2-frac-pi2n-frac1-sin2-frac2-pi2n

Comment: @mathlove Thank you and sorry for my insufficient searching.

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee Thank you and sorry for my insufficient searching.