# Using DeMoivre's Theorem to prove some identities regarding trigonometric functions

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

The following question is from a previous post. The reason that I am posting this again is because it had two questions which were not really related and hence, one of the questions was not answered. The question is from a book, "Mathematical Analysis - 2nd Edition" by Apostol. The question has three parts and is as follows:

---

1. By equating imaginary parts in DeMoivre's formula, prove that
   $$\sin{\left(n\theta\right)} = \sin^n\theta \left\lbrace \binom{n}{1}\cot^{n - 1}\theta - \binom{n}{3} \cot^{n - 3}\theta + \binom{n}{5} \cot^{n - 5}\theta - + \cdots \right\rbrace$$

---

2. If $0 < \theta < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, prove that
   $$\sin{\left(\left( 2m + 1 \right)\theta\right)} = \sin^{2m + 1}\theta P_m(\cot^2\theta)$$
   where $P_m$ is the polynomial of degree $m$ given by
   $$P_m\left( x \right) = \binom{2m + 1}{1}x^m - \binom{2m + 1}{3}x^{m-1} + \binom{2m + 1}{5}x^{m-2} - + \cdots$$
   Use this to show that $P_m$ has zeros at $m$ distinct points $x_k = \cot^2\left( \dfrac{\pi k}{2m + 1} \right)$ for $k = 1, 2, \dots, m$.

---

3. Show that the sum of zeros of $P_m$ is given by
   $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} \cot^2\dfrac{\pi k}{2m + 1} = \dfrac{m \left( 2m - 1 \right)}{3}$$
   and that the sum of theie squares is given by
   $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m} \cot^4\dfrac{\pi k}{2m + 1} = \dfrac{m \left( 2m - 1 \right) \left( 4m^2 + 10m - 9 \right)}{45}$$

---

As far as the solution is concerned, I have been able to prove the first part and upto proving the existence of the polynomial in the second part. For later parts, I do not have any insights in proceeding towards the solution.

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544228/finite-sum-sum-limits-k-1m-1-frac1-sin2-frack-pim/1083137#1083137

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**

---

**For part 2**, since you already showed the existence of the polynomial s.t. $$\sin \left( 2m + 1 \right)\theta = \left(\sin^{2m + 1}\theta \right)P_m(\cot^2\theta)$$ 
replace $\theta$ with $\frac{k\pi}{2m+1}$ and
$$\left(\sin^{2m + 1}\frac{k\pi}{2m+1} \right)\color{red}{P_m\left(\cot^2\frac{k\pi}{2m+1}\right)}=\sin \left(\left( 2m + 1 \right)\frac{k\pi}{2m+1}\right)=\sin{k\pi}=\color{red}{0}$$

---

**For part 3**, have you tried using [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)? It is a simple application of
$$\color{red}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}x_k}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\cot^2\frac{\pi k}{2m+1}=\color{red}{-\frac{a_{m-1}}{a_m}}=-\frac{-\binom{2m+1}{3}}{\binom{2m+1}{1}}=\\
\frac{(2m+1)2m(2m-1)}{1\cdot2\cdot3}\cdot \frac{1}{2m+1}=\frac{m(2m-1)}{3}$$
For the 2nd part of $3$ use the fact that 
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}x_k^2=\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}x_k\right)^2-2\sum\limits_{k<t}x_kx_t=\left(-\frac{a_{m-1}}{a_m}\right)^2-2\left(\frac{a_{m-2}}{a_m}\right)$$

Comment: What about the second part? How will I show that the roots are what we have to show?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh is it better now?

Comment: Yes! It was pretty simple. I could not see it, though!