# Prove by induction:$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi k}{n}\right)} = \frac{1}{3} \left(n^2 - 1\right)$

Tags: trigonometry, induction

For $n = 2$:

- Left-hand side (LHS):
  $\sum_{k=1}^{1} \frac{1}{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi k}{2}\right)} = \frac{1}{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)} = 1$
- Right-hand side (RHS):
  $\frac{1}{3}\left(2^2 - 1\right) = \frac{1}{3}(4-1) = 1$

Now, assume that the identity holds for some positive integer m, i.e.,

$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \frac{1}{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi k}{m}\right)} = \frac{1}{3}\left(m^2 - 1\right)$

We need to show that it holds for m+1:

$\sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi k}{m+1}\right)}$

We can use the identity $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{m+1}\right) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{m+1}\right)$

$\sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi k}{m+1}\right)} = \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{m+1}\cdot k\right)}$Now, you can use the assumption for m:$= \frac{1}{3}\left(m^2 - 1\right) + \frac{1}{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{m+1}\cdot (m+1)\right)}$$= \frac{1}{3}\left(m^2 - 1\right) + \frac{1}{\sin^2\left(\pi\right)}$

Any help will be appreciated
Tysm

Comment: Your equation $\sin(\pi/(m+1))=\sin(k\pi/(m+1))$ is not generally true. Also, it is not clear for me how you are applying the base case.

Comment: @Jam however, if $k=m$, then it becomes true.

Comment: @Eric If the question is to find out what is wrong, then it doesn't. This is most likely because the OP stops at a false conclusion. But if they are looking for a solution to the problem, then it would be a duplicate. Martin, please clarify the exact problem you are finding the answer of.

Comment: @Eric          Yes I don't know this question was already on mse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake here is that you thought $$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac1{\sin^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{m+1}\right)}=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac1{\sin^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{m}\right)}$$Which isn't true. If you want to find a proof of your claim, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544228/finite-sum-sum-limits-k-1m-1-frac1-sin2-frack-pim)

Comment: This downvote has no explanation so I will take it as pique.