# What is the partial sum formula for $\sum\limits_{j=2}^{x} \csc^2\left(\frac{\pi}{j}\right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I want to find the partial sum formula for:
$$
\sum_{j=2}^{x} \csc^2\left(\frac{\pi}{j}\right)
$$

I found a similar one, but I don't how to use it here:

[Finite Sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{\sin^2\frac{k\pi}{m}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544228/finite-sum-sum-limits-k-1m-1-frac1-sin2-frack-pim)

If I try to find approximation by the Fundamental Theorem of Engineering, $$\sin\left(x\right)\approx x$$

Then I get,
$$
\sum_{j=2}^{x} \csc^2\left(\frac{\pi}{j}\right) = \sum_{j=2}^{x} \frac{1}{\sin^{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{j}\right)} \approx \sum_{j=2}^{x} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{\pi}{j}\right)^2}
$$

Which gives in WolframAlpha:

$$
\sum_{j=2}^{x} \frac{1}{\left(\frac{\pi}{j}\right)^2} = \frac{2x^3 + 3x^2 + x - 6}{6\pi^2}
$$

And the graph of it was so close to the original sum that it blew my mind.

Comment: Doubt there’s a good formula tbh https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5Bcsc%5BPi%2Fj%5D%5E2%2C+%7Bj%2C+2%2C+300%7D%5D

Comment: You can get a good asymptotics: $$
\sum\limits_{j = 2}^n {\csc ^2 \left( {\frac{\pi }{j}} \right)}  = \frac{1}{{3\pi ^2 }}n^2  + \frac{1}{{2\pi ^2 }}n^2  + \frac{{2\pi ^2  + 1}}{{6\pi ^2 }}n + \mathcal{O}(1).
$$

Comment: In fact, the $\mathcal{O}(1)$ term can be replaced for instance by $C + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)$, where $$
C =  - \frac{{\pi ^2  + 3}}{{3\pi ^2 }} + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k 2^{2k + 2} \pi ^{2k} (2k + 1)B_{2k + 2} (\zeta (2k) - 1)}}{{(2k + 2)!}}}  = 0.10982248806823565160 \ldots \,.
$$ If you put more effort into your question, I can provide you with a detailed answer.

Comment: @Gary. Your last comment is superb !

Comment: @Mathematicianprime Do you think you can improve your question?

Comment: @Gary Improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shall derive the asymptotics of the sum for large $n$. Differentiation of the [Laurent series of $\cot(\pi t)$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laurent_Series_Expansion_for_Cotangent_Function) yields
$$
\csc ^2 (\pi t) = \frac{1}{{\pi ^2 }}\frac{1}{{t^2 }} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{{\pi ^2 }}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty (2k + 1)\zeta (2k + 2)t^{2k}  ,
$$
for $|t|<\pi$, where $\zeta$ is the [Riemann zeta function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2). Thus,
\begin{align*}
&\sum\limits_{j = 2}^n {\csc ^2 \left( {\frac{\pi }{j}} \right)}  = \frac{1}{{\pi ^2 }}\sum\limits_{j = 2}^n {j^2 }  + \frac{{n - 1}}{3} + \frac{2}{{\pi ^2 }}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {(2k + 1)\zeta (2k + 2)\sum\limits_{j = 2}^n {\frac{1}{{j^{2k} }}} } 
\\ & = \frac{1}{{3\pi ^2 }}n^3  + \frac{1}{{2\pi ^2 }}n^2  + \frac{{2\pi ^2  + 1}}{{6\pi ^2 }}n - \frac{{\pi ^2  + 3}}{{3\pi ^2 }} + \frac{2}{{\pi ^2 }}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {(2k + 1)\zeta (2k + 2)\sum\limits_{j = 2}^n {\frac{1}{{j^{2k} }}} } 
\\ & = \frac{1}{{3\pi ^2 }}n^3  + \frac{1}{{2\pi ^2 }}n^2  + \frac{{2\pi ^2  + 1}}{{6\pi ^2 }}n + C - \frac{2}{{\pi ^2 }}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {(2k + 1)\zeta (2k + 2)\zeta (2k,n + 1)} ,
\end{align*}
for any $n\ge 2$, where
$$
C =  - \frac{{\pi ^2  + 3}}{{3\pi ^2 }} + \frac{2}{{\pi ^2 }}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {(2k + 1)\zeta (2k + 2)(\zeta (2k) - 1)}  = 0.10982248806823565160 \ldots 
$$
and $\zeta(s,a)$ is the [Hurwitz zeta function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11). Employing the [known integral formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.11.E25) for this function, we find that
$$
\sum\limits_{j = 2}^n {\csc ^2 \left( {\frac{\pi }{j}} \right)}  = \frac{1}{{3\pi ^2 }}n^3  + \frac{1}{{2\pi ^2 }}n^2  + \frac{{2\pi ^2  + 1}}{{6\pi ^2 }}n + C+ \int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - (n+1/2)t} F(t)\,{\rm d}t} 
$$
for any $n\ge 2$, where
$$
F(t) =  - \frac{2}{{\pi ^2 }}\frac{{t/2}}{{\sinh (t/2)}}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {(2k + 3)\zeta (2k + 4)\frac{{t^{2k} }}{{(2k + 1)!}}} 
$$
for $t>0$. An application of [Watson's lemma](https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3#ii) then shows that
\begin{multline*}
\sum\limits_{j = 2}^n {\csc ^2 \left( {\frac{\pi }{j}} \right)} \sim \frac{1}{{3\pi ^2 }}n^3  + \frac{1}{{2\pi ^2 }}n^2  + \frac{{2\pi ^2  + 1}}{{6\pi ^2 }}n + C - \frac{{2\pi ^2 }}{{15}}\frac{1}{{2n + 1}}  \\ - \frac{{2\pi ^2 (40\pi ^2  - 63)}}{{2835}}\frac{1}{{(2n + 1)^3 }} - \frac{{2\pi ^2 (336\pi ^4  - 2000\pi ^2  + 2205)}}{{70875}}\frac{1}{{(2n + 1)^5 }} +  \ldots  
\end{multline*}
as $n\to+\infty$. Setting $m=2n+1$, we can write
\begin{multline*}
\sum\limits_{j = 2}^n {\csc ^2 \left( {\frac{\pi }{j}} \right)} \sim
\frac{1}{{24\pi ^2 }}m^3  + \frac{{4\pi ^2  - 1}}{{24\pi ^2 }}m + C' - \frac{{2\pi ^2 }}{{15}}\frac{1}{m}  \\ - \frac{{2\pi ^2 (40\pi ^2  - 63)}}{{2835}}\frac{1}{{m^3 }} - \frac{{2\pi ^2 (336\pi ^4  - 2000\pi ^2  + 2205)}}{{70875}}\frac{1}{{m^5 }} +  \ldots  
\end{multline*}
as $n\to+\infty$, with
$$
C' =  - \frac{{\pi ^2  + 2}}{{2\pi ^2 }} \!+\! \frac{2}{{\pi ^2 }}\!\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {(2k + 1)\zeta (2k + 2)(\zeta (2k) - 1)}  =  - 0.05684417859843101506 \ldots \,.
$$