# How to derive the sum $ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\cosh^2\left(\frac{\pi k}{n}\right)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation, chebyshev-polynomials

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\cosh^2\left(\frac{\pi k}{n}\right)}\end{align*}

I tried to solve with mathematica that shows [image]
Does anyone know how to derive this and does it is possible for Human to derive this(speaking seriously)

Comment: What is your motivation for wanting to solve this?

Comment: Recently I saw https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544228/finite-sum-sum-limits-k-1m-1-frac1-sin2-frack-pim this and I thought about cosh so i tried with mathmatica and...

Comment: also, why $ \cosh $   rather than $\cos  \; \; \; \; ?$

Comment: I saw the relative posts for cos and tan also

Comment: Does everyone here take my question as a joke(asking seriously)?

Comment: clearly it's already shown you how to derivce it. what else are you asking now

Comment: @JobHunter69     Mathematica doesn't provide any steps

Comment: If you are familiar with the digamma function, this is basically rewriting your summation, it does provide any thing useful. If you simply want a derivation, you can take a look at the definition of $\psi_q$:https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QPolyGamma.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you could have simplified the formula
$$\frac{\pi ^2}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\cosh^2\left(\frac{\pi k}{n}\right)}=$$
$$\psi _{e^{\frac{\pi
   }{n}}}^{(1)}\left(\left(1-\frac{i}{2}\right) n\right)+\psi
   _{e^{\frac{\pi }{n}}}^{(1)}\left(\left(1+\frac{i}{2}\right)
   n\right)-\psi _{e^{\frac{\pi }{n}}}^{(1)}\left(1-\frac{i
   n}{2}\right)-\psi _{e^{\frac{\pi }{n}}}^{(1)}\left(1+\frac{i
   n}{2}\right)$$

Next, you could bound the summation by the two integrals
$$I_1=\int_{1}^{n-1} \frac{dk}{\cosh^2\left(\frac{\pi k}{n}\right)}=\frac n \pi \left(\tanh \left(\frac{\pi  (n-1)}{n}\right)-\tanh
   \left(\frac{\pi }{n}\right)\right)$$

$$I_2=\int_{0}^{n-1} \frac{dk}{\cosh^2\left(\frac{\pi k}{n}\right)}=\frac n \pi \tanh \left(\frac{\pi  (n-1)}{n}\right) $$ which, compared to your summation, differ at most by $\pm \frac 12$.

All of that leads to the asymptotics

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\cosh^2\left(\frac{\pi k}{n}\right)}\sim -\frac 12+\frac{ \tanh (\pi )}{\pi }n-\frac{\pi  \tanh (\pi ) \text{sech}^2(\pi )}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$