# How can one find an identity for $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\tan^2(\frac{k\pi y}{n}) $?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, summation, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Using the function
$$
f(z)=\frac{n/z}{z^n-1}\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)^2\tag{1}
$$
and residue theorem
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=n^2-n\tag{2}
$$
can be found according to this post: [Prove that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{\cos^2\frac{\pi k}{n}}=n^2$ for odd $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442715/prove-that-sum-limits-k-0n-1-dfrac1-cos2-frac-pi-kn-n2-for-odd/442906#442906)

So I was wondering if it is possible to use the residue method to find an identity for
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\tan^2\left(\frac{k\pi y}{n}\right)\tag{3} 
$$
$0\leq y \leq 1$

and how? or alternative method if not.