# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac1{\sin^2 \frac{\left( 2k-1\right)\pi}{4n+2}}=2n\left( n+1\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation

Prove that $$\frac{1}{\sin^{2}\frac{\pi }{4k+2}}+\frac{1}{\sin^{2}\frac{3\pi }{4k+2}}+\frac{1}{\sin^{2}\frac{5\pi }{4k+2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sin^{2}\frac{(2k-1)\pi }{4k+2}}=2k(k+1)$$

Comment: Closely related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544228/is-sum-k-1m-1-frac1-sin2-frack-pim-fracm2-13-true-for-m?lq=1. It may help.

Comment: Using $$2\sin^2A=1-\cos2A$$ related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351337/product-of-cosines-prod-r-17-cos-fracr-pi15/1352365#1352365

Comment: It appears that the $k$s in the expanded sum should be $n$s.

Comment: Agree with @robjohn. Or, in the question header, the $k$'s should be $j$'s, and the $n$'s should be $k$'s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using $(7)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/173858), we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sin^2\left(\frac{2k-1}{4n+2}\pi\right)}
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\csc^2\left(\frac{2k-1}{2n+1}\frac\pi2\right)\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\sec^2\left(\frac{2n-2k+2}{2n+1}\frac\pi2\right)\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n\sec^2\left(\frac{k}{2n+1}\pi\right)\tag{3}\\
&=n+\sum_{k=1}^n\tan^2\left(\frac{k}{2n+1}\pi\right)\tag{4}\\[4pt]
&=n+n(2n+1)\tag{5}\\[12pt]
&=2n(n+1)\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\frac1{\sin(x)}=\csc(x)$
$(2)$: $\csc(x)=\sec\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)$
$(3)$: substitute $k\mapsto n+1-k$
$(4)$: $\sec^2(x)=1+\tan^2(x)$
$(5)$: use $(7)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/173858)
$(6)$: simplify

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment? they never do that's problem

Comment: It's been over $6$ years, so I don't think they will. The main motivation for someone to leave a critical comment would be so that the post could be improved. Of course, if someone leaves a critical comment, it is not anonymous, and they may fear reprisal. A glance at [my profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn#user-panel-votes) would show there is little chance of retribution.

Comment: I tool an interest in your excellent answer as I hoped it would solved my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4379583/is-there-any-identity-for-sum-k-1n-tan-left-theta-frack-pi-colorred only I'm new to contour integration so not sure if it is applicable to $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\tan\left(\theta+\frac{k\pi}{\color{red} {2n+1}}\right)$

Comment: This method gives the sum of the squares of the tangents, but the sum of the tangents is not so easy.

Comment: The reason we can sum the squares of the tangents and not the tangents this way, is that $\tan(-x)=-\tan(x)$ so the sum of the tangents around the circle cancels to $0$; whereas $\tan^2(-x)=\tan^2(x)$ so the sum of the squares of the tangents around the circle don't cancel and we can sum around the whole circle and divide by $2$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the method and why it works for squares of tangents. Nevertheless even if the method is not applicable to my question it is still interesting.