# Fractional exponent elementary symmetric polynomials.

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, symmetric-polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

I am wondering if there is any literature on relations between fractional power symmetric polynomials. For a particular example, with the variables $\textbf{x} = (x_1,x_2,\dots x_n),$, can we reasonably express
$$e^{(n)}_{\frac 12}(\textbf{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^nx^{\frac 12}_i$$ in terms of $e_1,e_2,\dots e_n,$
where:
$$e^{(n)}_j(\textbf{x}) = \sum_{1\le  j_1 < j_2 < \cdots < j_k \le n} x_{j_1} \dotsm x_{j_k} $$
? Square roots or radicals are to be expected if possible at all since for $n = 2$, we can simply use
$$e^{(2)}_{\frac 12} = \sqrt{x_1} + \sqrt{x_2} = \sqrt{x_1+x_2+2\sqrt{x_1x_2}} = \sqrt{e^{(2)}_1 + 2\sqrt{e^{(2)}_2}}$$
and technically this idea can be repeated enough to obtain some formula but it gets really tedious after $n = 3.$

I came upon this while trying to answer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4379583/is-there-any-identity-for-sum-k-1n-tan-left-theta-frack-pi-colorred/4381522?noredirect=1#comment9158576_4381522) question where it is asked whether there is a nice formula for:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\tan\dfrac{k\pi}{2n+1}.$$
Interesting thing is the above is an easy problem if the terms are squared:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\tan^2\dfrac{k\pi}{2n+1} = n(2n+1),$$
which follows from the fact that $x_i = \tan^2\dfrac{k\pi}{2n+1}$ are roots of the polynomial:
$$p(x) = \sum_{j=0}^n\binom{2n+1}{2j}(-z)^{n-j}.$$
This means that one way to find the sum of tangents would be to express
$$x_1^{1/2}+x_2^{1/2}+\dots +x_n^{1/2}$$
by a combination of the $n$ elementary symmetric polynomials $e^{(n)}_j,$ but this also where I am stuck right now.

Comment: First difficulty is that in the ring of polynomials there is no notion of a fractional power, while for polynomial functions the fractional powers are (generally) multi-valued. Otherwise put, if $\,x_i\,$ are the roots of $\,P(x)\,$ then $\,\sum x_i^{1/2}\,$ is the sum of half the roots of $\,P(x^2)\,$, but one of many possible "halves".

Comment: makes sense. For $n=3,$ one needs to solve a quartic equation:
$$(x^2-e_1)^2 = 4(e_2 + 2\sqrt{e_3}x),$$
so there is no a priori way to know which root will be the one I guess.