# Is there a closed form for $\sum_{k} \frac{1}{\cos (k)}$?

Tags: summation, closed-form, cyclotomic-polynomials

It is known that ($N$ positive integer)

$$
\frac{1}{2N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{\left[\cos\left( \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{4N} \right)\right]^2} = N
$$

see for example this MSE post [A curious identity on sums of secants](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219149/a-curious-identity-on-sums-of-secants).

Is there a closed form for the analogous sum where first powers are involved?

$$
S_1(N):= \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{\cos\left( \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{4N} \right)} 
$$

I suspect the answer won't be *entirely trivial* as $S_1(N)$ diverges logarithmically as $N\to \infty$.

I would be also interested in the analogous sum where the angles are even multiples of $\pi/(4 N)$, i.e., what about

$$
Z_1(N):= \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{\cos\left( \frac{n\pi}{2N} \right)} 
$$

?

Comment: @Carl I know the asymptotics (which I can compute with Euler-Maclaurin). An alternative approach (posted by D'Aurzio and now deleted) is to use the series expansion of $1/\sin(k)$ which has radius of convergence $\pi$. But my question is really if it's possible to obtain a closed form expression.

Comment: That sum appears as (part of) the susceptibility of the Ising model at the critical point. Some quantities of this model admit a closed form expression (for example the fidelity susceptibility)