# Value of $\tan^2(5)+\tan^2(10)+\tan^2(15)+...+\tan^2(85)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Calculate the exact value of $$\tan^2(5^\circ)+\tan^2(10^\circ)+\tan^2(15^\circ)+\cdots+\tan^2(85^\circ)$$

How to evaluate this sum of all these values? Is there a specific way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this in degrees?

Comment: Yeap, It's in degrees.

Comment: As $180/(10-5)=36$  use $\tan(36x)$  like  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951522/trig-sum-tan-21-circ-tan-22-circ-tan2-89-circ

Comment: Have a look at Cauchy's proof of Basel problem on Wikipedia. It exploits exactly such kind of trigonometric sums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\tan^2(5^\circ)+\tan^2(10^\circ)+...+\tan^2(85^\circ) = \tan^2\bigg(\frac{5\pi}{180}\bigg) +\tan^2\bigg(\frac{10\pi}{180}\bigg)+...+\tan^2\bigg(\frac{85\pi}{180}\bigg)$$

$$= \sum_{r=1}^{17}\tan^2\bigg(\frac{r\pi}{2\cdot18}\bigg)$$

Now note this result: [Prove that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\tan^{2}\frac{k \pi}{2n} = \frac{(n-1)(2n-1)}{3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2339/prove-that-sum-limits-k-1n-1-tan2-frack-pi2n-fracn-12n-1?rq=1)

We have $n = 18$ so then we get:

$$S = \frac{(18-1)(2\cdot 18 -1)}{3} =\frac{595}{3}$$

Comment: Can I know why 2*18?

Comment: @Mathxx To fit the form of the formula I provided.